# How can I configure the name of the "configuration" folder in an eclipse product?

Tags: eclipse

After exporting my eclipse product, I see the following files and folders:

```
+ configuration     (folder)
+ plugins           (folder)
- .eclipseproduct   (file)
- myProduct.exe     (file)
- myProduct.ini     (file)
```

I would like to rename the `configuration` folder to something else, or possibly move it to a less prominent location.

The reason is that customers can configure some things in my application by modifying certain application-specific XMLs, and I would like to put those XMLs in a "`configuration`" folder in the product's root folder, since that's the most intuitive name and location.

I'm afraid that if they see the current `configuration` folder (the one generated by eclipse, containing the `config.ini`) they will think this is where they should update/drop those XMLs. This is confusing at best and dangerous at worst, since there are quite delicate files in that folder that should not be manipulated.

I've looked for a way to configure the name or location of this eclipse-generated `configuration` folder without any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be changed by the product build.

Having the user put anything in any of the Eclipse install directories is not a good idea.

On a Mac system for example these directories are hidden inside an application package and will not normally be visible to the user at all. On other systems the install directory may be read only.

Comment: I normally would prefer to keep the users away from the installation folder, but these are advanced admin users and this is a requirement coming from the customer. They want everything to happen within the installation folder.
Thanks for your answer, though :). If no one comes up with a solution I will accept it.